# Creating Static readonly dictionary with enum as key in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I am trying to create a static class with some hard-coded reference information for a program. This static class contains an enum and a reference dictionary, which uses the enum to select a set of pre-defined numeric values. Here's an example of what I am doing below:

```
enum CellChemistry
{
    PbAc,
    NiZn,
    NiMH
}

public static class ChemistryInfo
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<CellChemistry, decimal> NominalVoltage = new Dictionary<CellChemistry, decimal>
    {
        { CellChemistry.PbAc, 2 },
        { CellChemistry.NiZn, 1.7 },
        { CellChemistry.NiMH, 1.2 }
    };
}
```

But I keep getting a syntax error on the line that says, `{ CellChemistry.PbAc, 2 },` to initialize the Dictionary saying,

`The Best overloaded Add method 'Dictionary<CellChemistry, decimal>.Add(CellChemistry, decimal)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments.`

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: The 2 is fine as there's an implicit conversion from 2 to decimals. But 1.7 and 1.2 need to be 1.7m and 1.2m respectively.

Comment: (And `CellChemistry` needs to be public or the field needs to be non-public.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton post your stuff as an answer (I think all the numbers need "m" as well btw).  I think you're right, and don't want to steal your rep.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: Done. I suspect there's a duplicate somewhere, admittedly... (It probably won't be in terms of dictionaries though.)

Comment: It's look like a bad design approach.. In my opinion CellChemistry should be a class that holds the name and the decimal value. No need to map the values every time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, as an alternative, would a static class with constant values defining the numbers be better computationally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's no implicit conversion from `double` to `decimal`. You can see this if you try to just assign the values to variables:

```
decimal x1 = 2; // Fine, implicit conversion from int to decimal
decimal x2 = 1.7; // Compile-time error, no implicit conversion from double to decimal
decimal x3 = 1.2; // Compile-time error, no implicit conversion from double to decimal
```

You want to use decimal literals instead - using an `m` suffix:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<CellChemistry, decimal> NominalVoltage = new Dictionary<CellChemistry, decimal>
{
    { CellChemistry.PbAc, 2 },
    { CellChemistry.NiZn, 1.7m },
    { CellChemistry.NiMH, 1.2m }
};
```

For consistency I'd *suggest* using 2m instead of 2, but you don't *need* to.

(You do need to either make `CellChemistry` public or make the field non-public in `ChemistryInfo`. Or make `ChemistryInfo` non-public. But that's a matter of accessibility consistency.)

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the numeric literals and was thinking there was a problem with the enums. Problem Solved!